# flutter RTL syntax error with "package:intl/intl.dart"

Tags: flutter, right-to-left

Hi i recently try to use a date Picker for flutter and i didn't find any Doc or tutorial for it so i open flutter gallery project and try to copy code .
as following the code i import "package:intl/intl.dart" library . 
after that in main.dart build function:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
    theme: new ThemeData.light(),
    home: new InitiateAppPage(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return new Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: child,
      );
    },
    );   }
```

Element 'TextDirection' from SDK library 'ui.dart' is implicitly hidden by 'intl.dart'.
any solution for this problem?

Comment: Date Picker [Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

import the namespace as below and use the alias name

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;
```

Comment: It works for me but I don't know why. Can you explain?

Comment: @tn2000
> It works for me but I don't know why. Can you explain?
Because intl class has the same name for its variable/mothed.

Answer (score 22):

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

..

```
textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr,
```

Comment: if using import 'package:intl/intl.dart'  can't use  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl  ,  above should be the answer  saved my day thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' hide TextDirection;
```

Should work.