# How to get the current locale text direction in Flutter using Intl

Tags: android, flutter, internationalization, right-to-left, flutter-intl

I'm creating a new flutter UI component that contains selection and getting more info about the product.

[image]

I want this component to support RTL also, So I need to get the current locale language direction which will allow me to know which corners of the selection shape will be rounded.

The `LTR` shape code is like this

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35),
    topLeft: Radius.circular(35),
    ),
  )
```

The `RTL` shape code will be like

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
    topRight: Radius.circular(35),
    ),
  )
```

I know that intl provides functionality to get the direction of specific text while I want to get the default direction of the current select locale, So if the current locale is Arabic, Farsi or any other right to left language I will return the `RLT` component. I don't know exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @chunhunghan I created a static method, this method takes the context and returns true based on the current locale of the app, because if you do not pass language code the function always returns false.

```
  import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;
  static bool isDirectionRTL(BuildContext context){
   return intl.Bidi.isRtlLanguage( Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode);
  }
```

Answer (score 34):

```
Directionality.of(context) == TextDirection.rtl
```

Comment: You need `import dart:ui`. In case of conflict with bidi_utils, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647795/flutter-rtl-syntax-error-with-packageintl-intl-dart.

Comment: It searches nearest Directionality widget and return its text direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use `intl.Bidi.isRtlLanguage()` with `import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;`
inside this function if you do not pass language code such as `en` or `ar`, it will use `Intl.getCurrentLocale()`

code snippet from `bidi_util.dart`

```
 static bool isRtlLanguage([String languageString]) {
    var language = languageString ?? Intl.getCurrentLocale();
    if (_lastLocaleCheckedForRtl != language) {
      _lastLocaleCheckedForRtl = language;
      _lastRtlCheck = _rtlLocaleRegex.hasMatch(language);
    }
    return _lastRtlCheck;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It worked with some edits, I will write the full answer