# How to calculate size of text string in flutter before rendering it?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have the text size and font, then how can I calculate the width and height of the  `String` before It is rendered on the screen? I need to know because I want to put it inside  a `Container` of the appropriate size before drawing it on the screen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `TextPainter` to `layout` the text and get its width and height.

For example:

```
final textSpan = TextSpan(
  text: 'Do you wanna build a snowman?',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
);
final tp = TextPainter(text: textSpan, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
tp.layout();
print('text width: ${tp.width}');
```

Console output:

> flutter: text width: 460.0

Comment: just for clarification, is the text direction necessary for the function to work properly? I don't know what is the language until runtime

Comment: Yes it is. The language should be based on the string you pass in, isn't it?

Comment: @HHH If you need to, you can get the text direction from device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61660786/1032613

Comment: I support multiple languages for input, I will see how to solve it

Comment: @WSBT maybe you can help in this related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73013522/why-is-this-method-that-determines-size-of-text-before-rendering-giving-differen)